# Spring boot with custom parent - working example

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, spring-boot

I am looking for working example of Spring Boot maven application without reference to spring-boot-starter-parent as a parent pom.

I found some words about that in Spring Boot Docs - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-your-own-parent but I still have problem with pluginManagement. Should I copy&paste all the pluginManagement section from spring-boot-starter-parent and spring-boot-dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I copy&paste all the pluginManagement section from spring-boot-starter-parent and spring-boot-dependencies?

That would work. Some might call it the "nuclear option" though (i.e. for your given use case you are unlikely to need all of it).

Comment: There is no any better solution?

Comment: That's the way Maven works (poms inherit from their parents). You probably don't need to copy any dependencies because you can use scope=import, but plugins need to be in the pom or its parent.